# Index of a plane curve is zero

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

There is a result that seems intuitive to me, but I don't know how to prove it.

Let $\gamma: [0, 1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a differentiable regular $\left(\gamma'(t) \neq 0, \forall t \in [0, 1]\right)$ plane curve such that

$$\gamma(s) = \gamma(t) \iff s = t,$$

and

$$\pi_{y}(\gamma(0)) \leq \pi_{y}(\gamma(t)) \leq \pi_{y}(\gamma(1)), \ \forall t \in [0, 1],$$

where $\pi_{y}$ is the canonical projection on the $y$-axis. Then the rotation index is zero, that is, the vector

$$\frac{\gamma'(t)}{|\gamma'(t)|}$$

does not complete any loop around the unitary circle $\mathbb{S}^{1}$.

Appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial fact here is that the mapping $\gamma$ is one-to-one. Here is a suggestion for an approach. See pages 26-28 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) for more details.

Let $\Delta = \{(s,t): 0\le s\le t\le 1\}$. Define the chordal map
$h\colon \Delta\to \Bbb S^1$ by 
$$h(s,t) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)}{\|\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)\|}, & s\ne t \\
\frac{\gamma'(s)}{\|\gamma'(s)\|}, & s=t
\end{cases}.$$
Then $h$ is everywhere defined and continuous (the latter requires a check). 
With a bit of work one can show there is a continuous function $\theta\colon \Delta\to\Bbb R$ so that $h(s,t) = (\cos(\theta(s,t)),\sin(\theta(s,t))$ for all $(s,t)\in\Delta$. You want to see that $|\theta(1,1) - \theta(0,0)|<2\pi$. (For a closed curve, the rotation index would be precisely $(\theta(1,1)-\theta(0,0))/2\pi$.)

Because of the hypothesis on the $y$-coordinate of $\gamma$, we know that for every $t$, $h(0,t)$ lies in the upper semicircle, and the same is true for $h(s,1)$ for every $s$. This means, in particular, that $|\theta(0,1)-\theta(0,0)|<\pi$ and $|\theta(1,1)-\theta(0,1)|<\pi$, so 
$$|\theta(1,1) - \theta(0,0)| \le |\theta(0,1)-\theta(0,0)|+|\theta(1,1)-\theta(0,1)|<2\pi,$$
as required.

Comment: But the y-coordinate may decrease, the only constraint is at the extremes.

Comment: Thank you, Ted.

Comment: You're welcome. Homotoping the tangent map to the chord map is the key issue.

Comment: @JoséPsicodélico Visually, this is similar to the GIFs [here](http://www.mathematik.com/Hopf/). Instead of tracing the tangents, you're tracing secants: first move one endpoint over, then the other. In each case the secant flops by strictly less than 180 degrees, so altogether it flops by less than 360. And this can be homotoped to sliding the tangent along.

Comment: Ok, interesting, Akiva. Thanks.